# Libgdx Skin not Updating when Changing Font Programmatically

Tags: java, user-interface, libgdx, truetype, skin

First, I loaded the skin as a json file. In the file, I put two BitmapFont defintions ("font" and "big-font") and left them practically blank (I did load a dummy ".fnt" file to prevent the parser from complaining). I then generated two FreeType Fonts using the following code:

```java
//start font generator
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/button-font.ttf"));
FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameters = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();

//default font (the sizes are arbitrary, since it did not work...)
parameters.size = 10;
BitmapFont defaultFont = generator.generateFont(parameters);

//big font
parameters.size = 100;
BitmapFont bigFont = generator.generateFont(parameters);
```

And set them as the skin fonts like so:

```java
skin.add("font", defaultFont, BitmapFont.class);
skin.add("big-font", bigFont, BitmapFont.class);
```

The problem is that the gui (particularly the TextButton, which uses the "font" font) does not seem to care about what I did programmatically and keeps using the dummy font that I've set in the json file.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to integrate ttf fonts and json skin parsing?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps :

1. First, create your font from a TTF file

   ```
   FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/button-font.ttf"));
   FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
   parameter.size = 10;
   BitmapFont defaultFont = generator.generateFont(parameter); 
   generator.dispose(); // don't forget to dispose to avoid memory leaks!
   ```
2. Create a blank skin using default constructor and add your font to the skin.

   ```
   Skin skin = new Skin();
   skin.add("font",defaultFont);
   ```
3. Add your atlas file to your skin.

   ```
   skin.addRegion(new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("mySkin.atlas")));
   ```
4. Load your Json file to your skin.

   ```
   skin.load(Gdx.files.internal("mySkin.json"));
   ```
5. then, in your JSON file you can reference “font”

   ```
   {
     font: font
   }
   ```