# Integrate Freetypefont into libGDX skin

Tags: libgdx

my problem is, like described in the Title, that i can not integrate an own BitmapFont into my libGDX skin. I searched a lot and there are many Topics with exact my problem, but their solution never work for me. Here is my code:

```
skin = new Skin();

    skin.add("default-font", StaticValues.generateFont(40, Color.BLACK), BitmapFont.class);

    FileHandle fileHandle = Gdx.files.internal("scene2d.ui/uiskin.json");
    FileHandle atlasFile = fileHandle.sibling("scene2d.ui/uiskin.atlas");

    if (atlasFile.exists()) {
        skin.addRegions(new TextureAtlas(atlasFile));
    }

    skin.load(fileHandle);
```

and now they say that i should remove this line:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: { default-font: { file: default.fnt } },
```

out of my JSON-File. But then this error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: scene2d.ui/uiskin.json
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:98)
```

...

```
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: No Drawable, NinePatch, TextureRegion, Texture, or Sprite registered with name: white
```

is there a simple solution for my problem?
Thanks in advance

Edit:
i already tried one other thing:
[Other Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45523878/libgdx-skin-not-updating-when-changing-font-programmatically), not working for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Libgdx Skin not Updating when Changing Font Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45523878/libgdx-skin-not-updating-when-changing-font-programmatically)

Comment: if i do it like in that solution, i get another error and it tells me that it can not load the JSON File, because of the missing font-declaration